# Data security with Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have a client that does not want the documents to permanently live in Azure. They are ok with moving files up to Azure to be indexed but after indexing they want the files to be removed from Azure and results to point to their on-prem storage.

Is this use-case possible with Azure Cognitive Search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can push any data into a search index that you want via the service's [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents) as long as you have network connectivity to the search service.

I'm not sure why your client doesn't want to store documents in Azure, but you should make sure they're aware that the ingested document data exists in the search index independently of any source data. That is, if he's concerned about his data being stored in Azure, the indexed data will always be stored in azure, since that's how the search service works.

If you're asking whether it's possible to point an [azure search indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-overview) to a datasource that is not hosted in Azure, then no, that's not generally supported. There are some third party organizations ([eg: Accenture, BA Insight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-data-sources-gallery#data-sources-from-our-partners)) that will host a connector to a non-azure datasource on your behalf though.

Comment: This is a good answer. It sounds like the client believes that content can only be indexed if it is stored in Azure. That's not true. As explained here you can push on-premise content using the REST API.